# Mysql recursive joins

Tags: mysql

I have a table "category" and a table "products". Category has **4 depth levels**.

The table category has a foreign key `category_fk` that references the same table, and one field with the modrewrite URL part. This field is named `mr`.

Products have a foreign key `category_fk` that references the table category

Only the categories on the last level have products, but the last category depth isn't always 4. It is possible that categories have only 2 or 3 levels.

My question is: Is it possible to do a query that returns all concatenated `mr` fields like this `cat1/cat2/cat3`, or all the structure without writing all left joins and aliases of table category like "as c1", "as c2"?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the table structure you described, but is possible if you adopt the *Nested Set Model*. The article [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) describes it (beside other models).

Comment: mmm this is interesant, i study it.  I see two limitations in this model. For one hand, in the deep level one, always you have only one element and i have more than 20. For the other hand, and more important limitation, the primary keys always are integer and auto increment. I import the data from an xml and ids are strings. I must mapp every result

Answer (score 0):

Based on this structure

```
create table category (id int, mr varchar(10), category_fk int);
create table products (id int, name varchar(100), category_fk int);

insert category values
(1, 'cat1', null),(2, 'cat2', 1),(3, 'cat3', 2),(4, 'cat4', 3),
(5, 'cat5', null),(6, 'cat6', null),(7, 'cat7', 5);

insert products values
(1, 'product A', 4),
(2, 'product B', 3),
(3, 'product C', 5),
(4, 'product D', 7),
(5, 'product E', 7),
(6, 'product F', 1);
```

The query

```
select p.name, substr(concat(
  ifnull(concat('/',c4.mr),''),
  ifnull(concat('/',c3.mr),''),
  ifnull(concat('/',c2.mr),''),
  ifnull(concat('/',c1.mr),'')),2)
from products p
left join category c1 on p.category_fk = c1.id
left join category c2 on c1.category_fk = c2.id
left join category c3 on c2.category_fk = c3.id
left join category c4 on c3.category_fk = c4.id
```

Notes

- substr strips the first /
- concat is in reverse order to the joins (parent first)
- concat '/' and null returns null, which is changed to '', otherwise it makes the main concat NULL

Comment: This is my solution for the moment but i don't use substr. I use concat_ws("/",c1.mr,c2.mr,c3.mr,c4.mr) as mr, thaks